# Unable to resolve module `assert` from `node_modules\@jest\console\build\BufferedConsole.js`: assert could not be found within the project

Tags: react-native, jestjs, node-modules, assert

I started getting this error all of a sudden on my working react-native app. I have tried all possible solutions available on other questions like clearing cache and all but nothing worked for me.

Even I tried to run my previous working apps and creating new app but getting the same error for all.

Please let me know if you need any further details to look into the issue.
Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "clean": "react-native-clean-project"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.18",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```